# Lookup Field Value JavaScript and CAML

Tags: javascript, sharepoint, caml

I have a lookup field in SP2013 list which I am trying to get list items using Javascrip and CAML. My function is as follow:

```
$(function () {if (healthInfoQuery && healthInfoQuery.Rows) {
        var liHealthInfoHTML = [];
        $('#healthinfo_list').toggle();
        $.each(healthInfoQuery.Rows, function (index, r) {
            liHealthInfoHTML.push('<li><a href="/Subsite/Documents/' + r.HealthInfo + '">' + r.Title + '</a></li>');
        });            
        $('#healthinfo_list ul').html(liHealthInfoHTML.join(''));
    }
});
```

Which HealthInfo is the lookup field. The return value is undefined. I need to return a value of the lookup using the above and then in my CAML, I will have HealthInfo field as ViewFields parameter.

```
<FieldRef Name='Title'/><FieldRef Name='HealthInfo'/>
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Resolved the issue by converting the lookup value "toString()"!